# Dark L before semi-vowels

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Not sure if this is the right place to ask on, but it's been bothering me for a while now. Do you still make a dark L before consonants like W, Y. 
For example - I'm all yours tonight. Will the L in "all" be a dark L?

Comment: Yes.  The l is darkened syllable finally and word finally.  So far as I can tell, the first sound in a following word has no relevance. (Medially, the first sound in a following syllable might be relevant.)

Comment: In a word like _hallway_, the tongue position at /l/ is velarized, and there's a slight rounding twitch at the edges of the mouth, but essentially the /l/ is non-syllabic [ʊ], prerounded by /w/.

Comment: @JohnLawler, that's an interesting take. I (B.A. linguistics, MS speech-language pathology) would never think of [ʊ] as articulated similarly to the dark l, which seems so velarized (as least in the dialect in my neck of the woods) as to not compare well with [ʊ], which is actually how I would transcribe misproduced velar /l/ for students who don't produce it well.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, so where do you think [ʊ] is pronounced, if it isn't velar?

Comment: @GregLee, at least for an SLP, you would never call a vowel "velar," as there is no obstructive contact with the tongue on the velum.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, Velarization is a kind of vowel color that is imposed on some consonants -- it does not require tongue contact with the velum (obviously, in the case of dark [l]).  I don't see why "velar" should assume tongue contact with the velum, while "velarization" does not.

Comment: @GregLee that's an unkind and unhelpful remark.

Comment: @KatherineLockwood, Sorry, I didn't mean to be insulting.  I meant that it is not a rational use of terminology to use different classificatory schemes for the articulation of dorsal consonants, which are distinguished principally by the shape of the tongue body, and for the articulation of vowels, which are also distinguished in this same way.  I'm happy to call a sound velar if it is made by raising and backing the tongue body, regardless of whether there happens to be contact between tongue and velum.

Answer (score 1):

### Before /w/, the "dark l" allophone will certainly be used

Before /w/, I can't imagine a native speaker who has "dark" and "light" allophones of /l/ using anything but dark l. The sequence /lw/ cannot occur within a single syllable in English, so the /l/ must be in a syllable coda, which is a position that strongly conditions the use of "dark l". I can't think of anything that would counteract this tendency before /w/.

Some speakers actually vocalize coda /l/ to something like [w], [ɰ] or [ɤ̯].

Also, some speakers who don't generally vocalize coda /l/ may elide it in some common words such as "always". I've also heard of this happening in other words with /lw/ such as "railway".

Jack Windsor Lewis wrote in "[The General American and General British Pronunciations of English](http://www.yek.me.uk/gavgb.html)"

> In GB [General British (English)] loss of an /l/ is very common in
>   *almost, always, railway, vulnerable, wholly* (rendering it homophonous
>   with holy) etc and syllable-finally some speakers vocalise /l/ to a
>   weak /u/ in forms like /`veɪu/ veil, /`reɪueɪ/ railway etc mainly in
>   markedly southeastern types of accent.

### Before /j/, I'm not sure but I doubt "light l" would be used

Before /j/, I've read that some native speakers will drop /l/ in some words, such as "billion".

While it's true that front vowels or front semivowels tend to condition brighter realizations of adjacent consonants, I've never read of this occurring in English for /l/ before /j/. I don't know enough phonetics to say if this happens or not.

Comment: The Southern dialect I grew up with nearly drops the /l/ completely in words like "million," but the dialect where I am now has a very strongly velarized [l] *along with a raised tongue-tip* in that context. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZmafy_v8g8) of Carl Sagan saying -illion words over and over again should be amusing regardless of what dialect you speak.